# jQuery .slideToggle not producing screen changes

Tags: jquery, css, menu, dropdown, slidetoggle

I am trying to get the #webdsn-drop div to appear when the #web is hovered over. I am using the .slideToggle jQuery but nothing happens when I scroll over it/ hover or click. I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. I also want the website to start with the webdsn-drop hidden.

The HTML is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div id="navbar">
 <div id="nav-container">
    <h1>PORTFOLIO</h1>
    <a href="#">Logo Design</a>
    <a href="#">Business Cards</a>
    <a href="posters+flyers.html">Posters & Flyers</a>
    <a id="web" href="#">Website Design</a>
 </div>
</div>

 <div id="webdsn-drop">
    <div id="border">
        <h1>WEBSITE DESIGN</h1>
    </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The CSS is:

```
body {
    background-color: #383838;
}

/*--------------Navigation Bar------------*/

#navbar {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fcfcfc;
    overflow: auto;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;

}

#nav-container {
    max-width: 950px;
    min-width: 745px;
    margin: 0 auto;


}

#nav-container h1 {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 10px;
    font-family: "calibri light";
    font-size: 25px;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
    margin-left: 5px;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;

}

#nav-container a {
    float: right;
    display: block;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-family: "calibri light", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;

}

#nav-container a:hover {
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
    transition: background-color 0.5s ease;
}

#nav-container a:active {
    background-color: #bfbfbf;
}

#nav-container h1:hover {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

#border{
    width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#border h1{
    position: absolute;
    border: solid;
    border-color: white;
    border-width: 1px;
    display: inline;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}


#webdsn-drop{
    background-color: #3f3f3f;
    margin-top: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 9;
    font-family: 'calibri light';
    font-size: 12px;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    height: 400px;
    color: white;

}
```

My jQuery is:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#web').hover(function() {
  $('#webdsn-drop').slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('#webdsn-drop').slideUp();
});

});
```

Comment: "but this isn't working" isn't a good description of a problem you're having.

Comment: "when the #web is hovered over" Then did you mean `$('#web').hover`, not `$('#web').click`?

Comment: no no. ive tried .click .hover .mouseenter but nothing seems to happen

Comment: "I also want the website to start with the webdsn-drop hidden." Then give it a `style="display:none"`.

Comment: keep eyes on console for errors .. if you got `$ is not defined` .. so you forgot to include jquery

Comment: add this line `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before include your js files .. in your case add it before `<script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Thank You very much it works now. Thats officially my first jquery function thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome @AbuN2286 :-)

Comment: Does anyone know how I can keep the slide down active after it happens and I move the mouse onto the slid down div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start `#webdsn-drop` with `display:none` so it's hidden when you first load the page:

```
<div id="webdsn-drop" style="display:none">
  <div id="border">
    <h1>WEBSITE DESIGN</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, since you're using hover, I'd suggest explicitly using `slideDown` and `slideUp` to show and hide the `div` when you hover and unhover:

```
$('#web').hover(function() {
  $('#webdsn-drop').slideDown();
}, function() {
  $('#webdsn-drop').slideUp();
});
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/n0qne6gx/1/

(Sorry, Stack Overflow snippets appear to be broken at the moment, so I can't share the working code inline.)